# "Error when running model: TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable"

Tags: pytorch

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-58ca628450f4> in <cell line: 56>()
     54 dict_dataloader_test = DataLoader(dict_dataset_test, batch_size=train_batch_size, pin_memory=True, drop_last=False)
     55 
---> 56 for it, (images, captions) in enumerate(dataloader_train):
     57     print(images)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    629                 # TODO(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76750)
    630                 self._reset()  # type: ignore[call-arg]
--> 631             data = self._next_data()
    632             self._num_yielded += 1
    633             if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in _next_data(self)
    673     def _next_data(self):
    674         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 675         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    676         if self._pin_memory:
    677             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data, self._pin_memory_device)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     47         if self.auto_collation:
     48             if hasattr(self.dataset, "__getitems__") and self.dataset.__getitems__:
---> 49                 data = self.dataset.__getitems__(possibly_batched_index)
     50             else:
     51                 data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]

TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable




This error got when i when i implement the code https://github.com/weimingboya/DFT/
```

"I attempted to execute the code as provided on the GitHub page, but encountered an issue. I'm seeking assistance to resolve this problem as I'm unsure why it occurred."

Comment: How is `dataloader_train` being defined?

Comment: sir https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xMJUmr6KhZkoglnvcpxYQTTUM1V4qeD4

can you access this google colab link for accessing my code

Comment: You need to reduce the problem size by providing a minimal reproducible example. That way we can try to help. Right now you have too many lines in your file.